# C++ getline or cin not accepting a string with spaces, I've searched Google and I'm still stumped!

Tags: c++, input, string, getline

First of all, thanks to everyone who helps me, it is much appreciated!

I am trying to store a string with spaces and special characters intact into `MessageToAdd`.

I am using `getline (cin,MessageToAdd);` and I have also tried `cin >> MessageToAdd;`.

I am so stumped! When I enter the sample input

> Test

Everything works as intended. However if I were to use

> Test Test Test

The whole console would just blink fast until I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

My style of putting variables at the top I've been told is obsolete. Please forgive me as I am still teaching myself and it's simply force of habit. I will be changing my style shortly after I get this solved :)

```
void AddMessage() {
    ifstream myReadFile;
    string str;
    string MessageToAdd;
    string myMessages[10];
    int i; // of course my famous i
    static string rowHtmlCloseTags;
    static string rowHtmlOpenTags;
    string replacement;

    myReadFile.open("C:\\Users\\Andrews\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\computerclass\\Debug\\outages.htm",ios::in);
    i = 0; //the start of my array
    rowHtmlCloseTags = "</b></td>"; // value that I want to replace with nothing
    rowHtmlOpenTags = "<td><b>";

    if(!myReadFile) // is there any error?
    {
        cout << "Error opening the file! Aborting…\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << endl;

        while (!myReadFile.eof())
        {
            getline(myReadFile, str);

            if (str == "<tr>")
            {            
                getline(myReadFile, str); //get the next line cause thats where the <td><b>Outage Message</b></td> is.
                size_t foundIndex = str.find(rowHtmlCloseTags); //does the sought string exist in this this line?
                if (foundIndex != str.npos) //if not no position
                    str.replace(foundIndex, rowHtmlCloseTags.size(), replacement); //replace the string
                else
                    std::cout << "Oops.. didn't find " << rowHtmlCloseTags << std::endl; //else throw a bitch

                foundIndex = str.find(rowHtmlOpenTags); //does the sought string exist in this this line?
                if (foundIndex != str.npos) //if not no position
                    str.replace(foundIndex, rowHtmlOpenTags.size(), replacement); //replace the string
                else
                    std::cout << "Oops.. didn't find " << rowHtmlOpenTags << std::endl; //else throw a bitch

                myMessages[i]=str;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    i=0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        cout << i << ") " << myMessages[i] << endl;
        i++;
        if (myMessages[i]=="")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the message you would like to see on the reader board.\n";
    cout << "Or enter 911 to go back to the main menu: ";
    cin.ignore(1080);
    getline (cin,MessageToAdd);

    if (str == "911") //go back to the main menu
    {
        system("cls");
        mainMenu();
    }
    else //insert the message into a blank spot in the array
    {
        i=0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            if (myMessages[i].empty())
            {
                myMessages[i]=MessageToAdd;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    //now rebuild the htm file with the new array
    CreateHtmlFile(myMessages);
}
```

Comment: Fire it up in a debugger and step through it.

Comment: This is a rather big function.

Comment: Why don't you just read in the whole file in one string and then take it from there? Seems unnecessary to read line by line.

Comment: @Anders: +1! I agree with you. Some streams iterators would do the trick. ;)

Comment: To everyone trying to puzzle their way through this function - the first half or so is essentially irrelevant to the question asked. Scroll down to the bottom of the code block, and the relevant part starts from the 5th line from the top.

Comment: +1 Anon, would have been enough with 5 lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll tell you one thing that's immediately wrong with your code, not your specific problem but a hairy one nonetheless.

I'm presuming that your `mainMenu()` function is calling this one. In that case, you appear to be under the misapprehension that:

```
if (str == "911") //go back to the main menu
{
       system("cls");
       mainMenu();
}
```

will return to your menu. It will *not* do that. What it will do is to call your main menu code afresh and eventually you will run out of stack space.

I suspect that what you should be doing is having a loop in `mainMenu()` and that code above should just use `return;` rather than calling `mainMenu()` recursively.

That and the fact that I think you should be comparing `MessageToAdd` against `"911"` rather than `str`.

---

Another thing I would do would be to put some temporary debug code in:

```
cout << "DEBUG A\n";
i=0;
while (i < 10)
{
    cout << "DEBUG B " << i << "\n";
    if (myMessages[i].empty())
    {
        cout << "DEBUG C\n";
        myMessages[i]=MessageToAdd;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        cout << "DEBUG D " << i << "\n";
    }
    cout << "DEBUG E\n";
}
cout << "DEBUG F\n";
```

and see what gets printed. Of course, you could trace the execution in a debugger but that would require you to do the work yourself. If you just post the output (first 100 lines if it's huge), then we can probably tell you what's wrong easily.

---

Actually, I think your problem is the `cin.ignore`. When I run your code, nothing works, neither `Test` nor `Test Test Test`. That's because it's ignoring the first 1080 characters I'm trying to input. Proof can be seen when you change those statements to:

```
cin.ignore(1);
getline (cin,MessageToAdd);
cout << MessageToAdd << "\n";
```

and you get `est` output when you enter `test`.

Take out the `ignore` line and try again. I'm not certain of this since you seem to indicate that `Test` works but I can't see this as being correct.

---

So here's what you need to do (at a bare minimum):

- get rid of the `cin.ignore` altogether.
- use `return` rather than `mainMenu()`.
- use `if (MessageToAdd == "911")` instead of `if (str == "911")`.
- let us know how it goes then.

Comment: you are are amazing! Your review is top notch! I have no one to learn from or review my code and your intuition about mainMenu() was spot on. I added a loop in mainMenu() and have since changed all returns. My code works now and I couldn't be more happy. Again, thank you for answering questions on the forum. I wouldn't learn without your amazing response.

Comment: @Coding, no problems. SO is actually a good way to learn if you have specific problems and have already tried. The swarm will come down like a ton of bricks on people who ask "Please write a function to do this" but we're more than happy to help out those who have already put a fair effort into the job. Cheers and good luck. Now that's enough about you, let's talk about me some more :-)